# Unit testing function using File.Exists

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

How can I unit test this type of function? Of course I can't create real files and I can't make any changes to *Example* class and *Func* to make it easier to test.

As I found out, mocking static `Exists` is not possible using popular free frameworks like moq. I found some frameworks to mock filesystem like System.IO.Abstractions (https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions) but in all samples I found, methods (like `CreateDirectory` etc. - here `Exists`), are called from mocked object and I'm not sure how to adapt it to this method (if it is possible).

```
public class Example
{
    public int Func()
    {
        if(System.IO.File.Exists("some hard-coded path"))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say `Of course I can't create real files`? One clear option is to test things on your local computer.

Comment: Why can't you create real files? why can't your test setup create a file and your cleanup will delete it (or vice versa)? You can Mock such calls with some commercial Mock frameworks (e.g. TypeMock), but I'm not sure this would be the right solution here...

Comment: If you cannot make changes to the Example class, what are you going to do if your test fails?

Answer (score 6):

How about creating a `FileWrapper` class and passing it in as a dependency in your test?

```
public class Example
{
    private IFileWrapper _fileWrapper;

    public Example()
        : this(new FileWrapper())
    {
    }    

    public Example(IFileWrapper fileWrapper)
    {
        _fileWrapper = fileWrapper;
    }

    public int Func()
    {
        if (_fileWrapper.Exists("some path")
        {
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

then define `FileWrapper` as:

```
internal class FileWrapper : IFileWrapper
{
    public bool Exists(string path)
    {
        return File.Exists(path);
    }
}
```

and the interface `IFileWrapper` as:

```
public interface IFileWrapper
{
    bool Exists(string path);
}
```

Then your test can create a mock of the `IFileWrapper` and pass this into your class under test (using Moq here):

```
[TestMethod]
public void Func_ShouldCheckFileExists()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockFileWrapper = new Mock<IFileWrapper>();
    mockFileWrapper.Setup(_ => _.Exists(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

    var example = new Example(mockFileWrapper.Object);

    // Act
    int returnValue = example.Func("test path");

    // Assert
    Assert.Equals(returnValue, 1);
}
```

It's a bit more work, but you can build up a library of such wrappers and reuse them across your code base.

If you really can't modify your code, then perhaps a look at Microsoft's [Moles](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/moles-isolation-framework-for-net/#) project, or the newer [Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) project might help you.

Comment: The question is can we modify the example class? also, IMHO, such solution would add unnecessary complication to the product code, just for testing... not sure that in this specific case it's worth it...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, i re-invite the mock wheel, but simple code hereunder is working for me, it used in many my Unit Tests:
I use *public bool isUT == true* in Unit Test, else == *false*;
bool function, similar to Example in the question, is

```
public bool IsFileExist(string pathFile) => x.Exists(pathFile);
```

with *FileWrapper* as above

```
internal class FileExist : IFileWrapper
{
    public bool Exists(string path) => File.Exists(path);
}
public interface IFileWrapper
{
    bool Exists(string path);
}
```

*protected IFileWrapper x;* is either *null* in business run, or injected dependency from Unit Test with the reference to mock class

```
public class mock : FileOp, IFileWrapper
{
    private string myPath { get; set; }

    internal mock(string myPath = "")
    {
        base.x = this;
        this.myPath = myPath;
    }

    public bool Exists(string path) => path == myPath;
}
```

When myPath contains the same string as in request, it simulate existing file, else IsFileExist return false.